# rspec capybara selector rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write an rspec test that will;

- visit the store page
- select a value in the Countries select box
- and test that the value exists (initially in the Countries box but I would also be testing for cities which is dependent on Country in the second test)

HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/password_resets.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/people.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/products.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/store.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/password_resets.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/people.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/products.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/store.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/users.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="NcsV3Ve7QqLTjeLNz5MLuCxzvG8urc63NiDk7RZTGtM=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="/" id="logo">sample app</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav btn-group navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline">
                  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="/signin">Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


      <div class="container">




<h2>some text</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/store/show" method="get"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

          <label for="catalogue_country">Country</label>
          <select id="countries_select" name="catalogue[country_id]"><option selected="selected" value="1">France</option>
<option value="2">Italy</option>
<option value="3">United Kingdom</option></select>

        <div class="pull-right">
          <input class="btn brn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
</form>        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


        <footer class="footer">
  <small>
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Rails Tutorial</a>
    by Michael Hartl
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>


      <pre class="debug_dump">--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
controller: store
action: index
</pre>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

My test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "index" do

  subject { page }

  before do

    visit store_path

    select "United Kingdom", :from => "catalogue[country_id]"

  end

  it { should have_select('country_id', :selected => 'United Kingdom') }

end
```

The failures

Failures:

1) index 
     Failure/Error: visit store_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

The rails console [app.store_path] verifies that store_path is '/store'

The select boxes are dynamically populated according to the directions in this blog [posting](http://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/)

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

There are the routes

```
  match '/store', to: 'store#index', as: :store, via: 'get'

  get 'store/show'

  match 'store/update_cities', to: 'store#update_cities',  as: :update_cities, via: 'get'

  match 'store/update_currencies', to: 'store#update_currencies',  as: :update_currencies, via: 'get'
```

Its one index page (store_path) which has a countries select box.

This is the store controller

```
  def index

    @countries = Country.all

    @cities = City.where("country_id = ?", Country.first.id)

    @currencies = Currency.where("country_id = ?", Country.first.id)

    @locations = Location.where("city_id = ?", Location.first.id)

    @products = Product.where("Location_id = ?", Product.first.id)

    @plugs = Plug.where("Location_id = ?", Plug.first.id)

  end

  def show
  end

  def update_cities

    @cities = City.where("country_id = ?", params[:country_id])

    respond_to do |format|

      format.js

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to visit a specific store, or listing all the stores ?

in your case you are trying to visit a specific store which you need to pass a parameter for it in this case the store id

To know the exact path write in the console:

```
rake routes
```

you will find each path to its url, if you want to list all the stores you need to write:

```
stores_path
```

instead of:

```
store_path
```

store_path is /store/:id

Comment: I have added the routes and controller above, the '/store' path is routed to store_index.html.erb, this one page has 3 select boxes, first countries, then cities, currencies.  Its the values in the select boxes I wish to test.

Comment: Does the Country model has any entries? may be in seeds or something?. Because if it has not, it means that there are no entries in the Country Model. In that case you are trying to find id of a nil object As you are saying in the index action: Country.first.id,

To test it by yourself, try a debugger in the index action

Comment: You can either define list of countries in the seeds, or try to create a factory for it

Comment: Your last comment was correct, the development DB was populated but the test was empty,
Poplated test db;
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test